# Python Dash-Cytoscape Node Pie Chart Slice Label

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm new to dash-cytoscape in python and I'm trying to use the pie-style feature for nodes (https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape/blob/master/demos/usage-pie-style.py).

Does anyone know if we can add a label to each of the pie slices, like in this picture below ?

[Sample Pie-chart Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOe9I.png)

I suspect that there would be some input like 'pie-1-text':'ABC' or 'pie-1-label':'DEF' to be added to the stylesheet, but I could not find any documentation on that.

```
stylesheet={
            'selector': 'node',
            'style': {
                'width': '60px',
                'height': '60px',
                'content': 'data(id)',
                'pie-size': '80%',
                'pie-1-background-color': '#E8747C',
                'pie-1-background-size': 'mapData(foo, 0, 10, 0, 100)',
                'pie-2-background-color': '#74CBE8',
                'pie-2-background-size': 'mapData(bar, 0, 10, 0, 100)',
                'pie-3-background-color': '#74E883',
                'pie-3-background-size': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 0, 100)'
            }}
```

Thank you all !

Comment: add a style like `'label': 'my name is ...'` There is documentation https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels

Comment: this works for the node label defined in the element level what I'm trying to do is to add labels for the pie slices, for example with the % of each pie slice